Question quality standards
Why doesn't the following question meet quality standards?
Title:Ripple ledger
Question: How can one download and analyse Ripple ledger?
Tag:Ripple
I also made the title the same as the question and expanded question slightly, since it is really a very simple question and I can't make it wordier without being repetitive. Didn't work. 
